# method in class AuthenticationManagerBuildier cannot be applied to given type

Tags: java, spring-boot, entity, encode

I am trying to encrypt a password into the database with spring security however i get the error. My spring security class is returning an error when i try to encode the password. I am not sure where i am going wrong.

This image shows the error being thrown by the security class:

[image]

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired  
private UserService userService;

protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
  }

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }
}
```

**ApplicationAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java**

```
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication
        authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("authenticated_user", user);
    super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public Response createUser(User user) {
      if( user == null || user.getId() == null){
          throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Empty", "Missing Data Exception");
      } else {
          user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
          userRepository.save(user);
          return new Response(user.getId(), "Customer Created Successfully");
      }

 }
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {
@NotBlank
private String surname;

@NotBlank
@Size(min = 5, max = 20, message = "Please enter between {min} and {max} characters.")
private String phoneNumber;

@NotBlank
@Size(min = 5, max = 100, message = "Please enter between {min} and {max} characters.")
private String password;
}
```

**RegisterController.java**

```
@RestController
public class RegisterController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/users")
public Response createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user){
    return userService.createUser(user);

   }
 }
```

Comment: `UserService` is not `UserDetailsService`. `auth.userDetailsService` expects instance of `UserDetailsService`.

Comment: thank u that was the error , now the problem is solved

Comment: This error is fixed however i am now getting an html login page when i try to query all users in the database. Previously i was getting a json response and i still want a Json response